# Change validation message which using '.' in between name of field in laravel5.1?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When I am using angularjs and laravel, I am sending object to server as follows,

```
   {
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "",
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Passport",
        "status": 1
    }
}
```

My form validation `class` is,

```
 protected $rules = [
    'title' => ['required', 'max:125'],
    'category.id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:file_categories,id']
];
```

And it is working fine but the error message is like follows,

```
The category.id field is required.
```

I want to change this to `The category field is required.`

for this, I have updated `validation class`,

```
'attributes' => [
        'category.id' => 'Category',
    ],
```

But it is not working? How can I fix this?

Comment: `'attributes' => [
        'category' => ['id' => 'Category',],
    ],` try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

In View Page you can replace the error message text:

```
<?php $errmsg=$errors->first('category.id'); 
$errmessage=str_replace(".id"," ",$errmsg);
if($errmsg !="")
{
?>
  <div class="error"><?php echo $errmessage ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
```